# Something other than libcurl

Tags: c++, visual-c++, libcurl

So I've been messing around with libcurlpp doing things like trying to download HTML files or HTTP POST requests but I always get around 4 errors like

```
1>MyProgram.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init
1>MyProgram.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt
1>MyProgram.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform
1>MyProgram.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup
```

And the one time I actually got it to compile whenever I run it I get SEVERAL DLL errors even if I move the proper DLL's into the folder with my executable the compiler spits out more errors about ?PDB's? if I remember properly

Any who I'm done with libcurl for now could anyone suggest something else preferably well documented because I'm pretty new at this.

And yes I've already searched for something with little results. Much thanks in advance!!!

EDIT: Got it to work using SFML Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you looked at [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)? It seems to me like the most obvious alternative.

Comment: I just remeber seeing it when I was looking at some libs to work with. I'll see if I can get it working

Comment: Please correct "then" to "than" in the question's title.

Comment: Better?(Filling character quota)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).  It's a multi-media library, mainly intended for game development, but it happens to have facilities for processing HTTP.  It's very easy to use, the following downloads this page:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Http Http("stackoverflow.com");    
    sf::Http::Request req("/questions/9892198/something-other-than-libcurl");    
    sf::Http::Response page = Http.SendRequest(req);

    std::cout << page.GetBody();
}
```

Of course, there's a little more work to be done if you want to handle more complex situations like redirects.

Comment: Wow that seems really easy compared to curl! I'm gonna play around with POCO first and if all else fails I might try this out

Comment: After getting it working I ran it and it crashed Visual Studio HAHA

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here is the trivial Poco program:

```
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Poco::Net;

int main () {
  HTTPClientSession session("stackoverflow.com");
  HTTPRequest request("GET", "/questions/9892198/something-other-than-libcurl");
  HTTPResponse response;

  session.sendRequest(request);
  std::cout << session.receiveResponse(response).rdbuf();
}
```